# How can i merge two tables in pandas, where only specific rows gets merged?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two data tables as seen below. I want to merge the two tables so the closest actual date matches the planned date. I want the result to be as shown in df3. How can i do that in pandas?

df1 =

| ID | pld_date | act_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-09-25 | NaT |
| 1 | 2023-09-11 | NaT |
| 1 | 2023-09-04 | NaT |
| 1 | 2023-09-18 | NaT |

df2=

| ID | pld_date | act_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NaT | 2023-09-07 |
| 1 | NaT | NaT |
| 1 | NaT | NaT |
| 1 | NaT | NaT |

df3=

| ID | pld_date | act_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-09-25 | NaT |
| 1 | 2023-09-11 | NaT |
| 1 | 2023-09-04 | 2023-09-07 |
| 1 | 2023-09-18 | NaT |

I have used both merge_asof and merge. and got the following resutlt:

```
df3 = pd.merge_asof(left=df2, right=df1, direction='nearest', left_index=True, right_index=True)
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='ID', how='left')
```

df3=

| ID | pld_date | act_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-09-25 | 2023-09-07 |
| 1 | 2023-09-11 | 2023-09-07 |
| 1 | 2023-09-04 | 2023-09-07 |
| 1 | 2023-09-18 | 2023-09-07 |

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed perform a double merge, since you want a one-to-one merge, first [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) to find the closest match in `df1` for each non-null `df2` date, then [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) back using the found date (and ID, optionally):

```
tmp = pd.merge_asof(df2[['ID', 'act_date']].dropna(subset=['act_date']),
                    df1[['ID', 'pld_date']].sort_values(by='pld_date'),
                    by='ID', direction='nearest',
                    left_on='act_date', right_on='pld_date')

out = df1.drop(columns='act_date').merge(tmp, on=['ID', 'pld_date'], how='left')
```

Output:

```
   ID   pld_date   act_date
0   1 2023-09-25        NaT
1   1 2023-09-11        NaT
2   1 2023-09-04 2023-09-07
3   1 2023-09-18        NaT
```

Intermediate `tmp`:

```
   ID   act_date   pld_date
0   1 2023-09-07 2023-09-04
```

Comment: Thank you soooo much! it works exactly as i want it! :).